# Bizarre error messages when monitoring random integers

Tags: warning-messages, random, monitoring

I am doing

```
tbl = {};
Monitor[
 Do[AppendTo[tbl, RandomInteger[{1, 100000}, 2]], 100000],
 Length[tbl]
]
```

(well in fact I am doing something less boring but what I want to ask about happens here too)

Every now and then the following message is generated:

```
RandomInteger::array: The array dimensions 2 given in position 2 of
RandomInteger[{1,100000},2] should be a list of non-negative machine-sized integers
giving the dimensions for the result.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Now such message when I execute it in version 11.3 on macOS. Try to restart the kernel. Btw., this use of `AppendTo` slows down things needlessly: A randomm table of that size can be obtained with `RandomInteger[{1, 100000}, {100000, 2}];` in a 20000th part of the time.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Mine is 11.0.1 on Windows 10. The reason I use `AppendTo` is that what I actually want to do requires some time at each step, so I would like to place a `ListPlot` as the second argument of `Monitor`, to watch the picture while it gradually emerges.

Comment: Run the code 5 times on a fresh kernel, and no error message. Tested on 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Comment: Error `Do::itform` in MMAv9.

Comment: Hm. Maybe `tbl = {};
Monitor[Do[AppendTo[tbl, RandomInteger[{1, 100000}, {2}]], {100000}], 
 Length[tbl]]` will make it work in version 9?

Comment: @Hector Does this error appear from the beginning or later during execution of the loop?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Apparently, there has been an evolution on what is an iterator. Schumacher's comment fixes it. I left the computer running while I left for dinner. No problem in MMA9 after changing the iterator to conform to v9 specs.

Comment: @Hector Seems like you've pinned it down. Could you elaborate on it in an answer? E. g. what are specifications concerning iterators? Or what is the internal representation on an iterator in `Do[...,{1000}]` or alike?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I cannot write an answer … I only tried to give another data point to help solve the mystery. I only pasted into my MMAv9 and your code did not run. Using the comment by Henrik, your code does run. But the issue I had was related to `Do`. The issue you had was related to `RandomInteger` (at least from the error message). I cannot confirm that adding curly braces around the 2 would solve the problem in your version of MMA. In any case, the reference for iterators is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeGeneralNotationsAndConventions.html#27272).

Comment: Is this happening when run in a fresh kernel? Or is there any other thing happening?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Cannot reproduce it now. I remember doing lots of graph monitoring when this happened. Seems like I better close this question.

Comment: It was a perfectly good question (albeit with imperfect info). The key was use of `Monitor`, which interacts with the kernel using a thread. THere was a bug, now fixed, in (mis)handling of a signal that hits at an inopportune time; there was cross-talk between threads and the `Do` iterator was getting messed up. If you provide full code to replicate we can try testing in a current kernel to make sure we fully made it go splat (the bug, I mean, not your code). Can do this either in this MSE question or through Tech Support.